# Enable ScrollPane when components exceed inside a text area

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Before anything else there might be some people who already asked this question. However, i am certain that I couldn't google it. Anyway, I have a scrollPane which has a viewPortView of textArea.  My question is I would like to show my scrollpane when i insert numerous components inside my textArea. How am i supposed to do this? I have no idea and I'm not that expert with Javax Swing. 
Code goes like this:

```
textArea = new JTextArea();
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
   textArea.setBounds(0,50,520,550);
   textArea.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   scrollPane.setBounds(textArea.getBounds());
   scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is I would like to show my scrollpane when i insert numerous components inside my textArea.

A text area displays text, not components. The scrollbars will appear automatically when you actually add text to the text area.

```
textArea.setBounds(0,50,520,550);
```

Don't use setBounds. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. In particular a JScrollPane will only work properly when you use layout managers.

```
//textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

When you create a JtextArea use code like the above. This will allow the text area to determine its own preferred size. Then scrollbars will appear once you add more than 5 rows of text.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for more information and working examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea! I am basically new to Java Swing so I'm just using what I think is right and what I think I can do. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Just for information,

If you have multiple lines in your text area, the scroll bar is by default scrolled to the end of the text area. To keep the lines in the text area wrapped and scroll bar to the top of the text area, following code would help

```
    textArea .setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea .setLineWrap(true);
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea .getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```